# Aztec qrcode encoding error correction BwipJs

Tags: aztec-barcode, bwip-js

I am generating Aztec code with bwip-js in an angular app and i'm trying to match another aztec code generated by another system but no success.

I noticed the 2 codes have 2 differents sizes and I suppose this can be due to error correction levels.

**Is there a way to configure bwip-js error correction level for Aztec codes encoding ?**

Here is my code to generate the QRcode SVG.

```
    buildSvgQrcode(QRCodeValue: string): string {
        return bwipjs.toSVG({
            bcid: QrcodeType.AZTECCODE, // Barcode type
            text: QRCodeValue, // Text to encode
            scale: 1,
            paddingleft: 10,
            paddingright: 10,
            includetext: true, // Show human-readable text
            textxalign: 'center', // Always good to set this
        });
    }
```

Here are the 2 aztec codes: First is the target, second is the one I generated
[image: Aztec code target][image: Aztec code I generated]